# How to enable nested interrupts in msp430g2553?

Tags: interrupt-handling, msp430

I want to enable nested interrupts on msp430 as I want to use UART in the ISR of a Timer.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever `msp430` microcontroller is about to start to execute an interrupt handler function, the first thing it does is to disable the global "interrupts enabled" flag, which is a bit in the status register `r2`. That effectively prohibits interrupt nesting by default.

To work around this, enable interrupt by setting the register flag back to 1 at the start of your interrupt handler functions. To simplify the syntax, there's actually an `eint` instruction for this:

```
asm("eint");
```

Typically there are also compiler-specific macros for emnabe that let you avoid writing assembly code. This should work both with GCC and IAR:

```
__enable_interrupt();
```

(Please, do not abuse interrupt nesting. In most cases there's absolutely no need for it. It's almost certainly a better idea to change your design than to go for it.)